# How to get objects from Array Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a array like this:

```
Array[2]

    0: Array[1] 0: Object
                     color: "d64b23"
                     hasta_sayisi: 84412
                     il: "TOKAT"
                     __proto__: Object
                    length: 1
                   __proto__: Array[0]

    1: Array[1]
                 0: Object
                   color: "499a84"
                   hasta_sayisi: 123068
                   il: "SİVAS"
                   __proto__: Object
                  length: 1
                  __proto__: Array[0]
```

I want to get objects from this array.So output should like this:

```
{
 color: "d64b23",
 hasta_sayisi: 84412,
 il: "TOKAT"
},
{
 color: "499a84",
 hasta_sayisi: 123068,
 il: "SİVAS"
}
```

How can we achive this with Javascript?

Thanks

Comment: How do you have this array?

Comment: Can the sub-arrays have more than one element, or will they always be just one element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you could figure it out since all you need to do is to iterate over the array and grab the first index of each nested array.

In any case, here's a solution using map:

```
var result = array.map(function(a) {
    return a[0];
});
```

---

If each nested array could have multiple items, then you can use `.reduce()` with an inner `.map()` and `.concat()`

```
var result = array.reduce(function(res, a) {
    return res.concat(a.map(Object));
}, []);
```

The `Object` is the constructor function which will simply return the first argument it's given. It's a little shorter than passing an anonymous function.

---

For that matter, we could just use `.concat()` with `.apply()`

```
var result = [].concat.apply([], array);
```

This will flatten your nested arrays out to a single dimension.